# What will happen in Java when I use a method of the super class which has not been written?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

Consider the Java code below, what would happen if there were no paintComponent method in JPanel class?

...

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ShapesJPanel extends JPanel
{

     public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
     {
       super.paintComponent( g );
       //more codes here  
     }
}
```

Comment: Simply rename paintComponent to something else (e.g. dummyMethod()) and try to compile. You will find out what happens yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If that's the specific situation you're asking about then it's always there.
2. If you're asking in general then it won't compile.

Answer (score 9):

It won't compile. If it was there at compile time but not at runtime, then it will throw an Error.

Comment: Is there a situation I'm not aware of where it would not be there at runtime? The compiler can, must and will statically check this, so there's no option to have it 'not be there' after a successful compile (or am I missing something)?

Comment: Compile the ShapesJPanel class but deploy it with a different version of JPanel class which doe not have this method.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be an implementation in the super class.

`JPanel` implements `paintComponent()`.  So, you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

### At compile time

- The method should present in any of the class in super class hierarchy otherwise compilation will fail
- The method of the class from that hierarchy ( starting from bottom)  will get called

### At run time

- If method does not found it will throw an error